# Issues with OnCollisionEnter2D in unity 2D

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am developing a tetris game in Unity 2D in C#. I want to detect collisions between a sprite and quad as a wall, but my OnCollisionEnter2D function doesn't work.

I put my sprites inside an array which is Gameobject type. I have both Rigidbody2D and BoxCollider 2D both on my sprites and the Quad(Wall).
My Quad's(wall) tag is "obstacle". Can anyone help me? I would appreciate any kind of help related to my code.

Here is my piece of code for CollisionEnter2D:

```
public void CollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "obstacle") {
            Debug.Log ("Hit");
        }
```

Comment: Did you make the collider a trigger?

Comment: Which one of the colliders?

Comment: I need to stop my gameobject oncollision and not let it pass through the Quad(Wall)

Comment: And I also want my next Gameobject inside array start motion as soon as my previous Gameobject collides with the wall @StevenWestbrook

Answer (score 1):

See if your Rigid body 2d  on the inspector is set to **kinematic** instead of **dynamic** and your box collider has **'is trigger'** checked. See if that works, also I used prefabs for spawing obstacles and when I tried to put a spawner on screen with the prefabs deleted from the scene, the collision didn't detect but when I added it back on the screen, it worked. I'm not really sure why but see if the above solutions work.

Also change

```
public void CollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
```

to

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
```